# Beginners Moq question on Verifying

Tags: installation, moq, verify

I'm just playing around with Moq and I cannot work out how to get a call to `Verify` to work as expected. My problem seems to be that the method I'm calling on the SUT is not being called. Here's my code to test:

```
public class ImageHandler : BaseHttpHandler
{
   public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
   {
       var person = new Person();

       this.DoPerson(person);

       context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

       if (context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("jellyfish.jpg"))
       {
           context.Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\Temp\jf.jpg");
       }
       else if (context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("koala.jpg"))
       {
           context.Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\Temp\k.jpg");
       }
       else
       {
           context.Response.Write("File not found.");
       }

   }

   public virtual void DoPerson(Person person)
   {

   }
}
```

Here is my MSpec test:

```
[Subject("Process")]
public class When_Given_Person
{
    private static Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContext;

    private static Mock<HttpRequestBase> httpRequest;

    private static Mock<HttpResponseBase> httpResponse;

    private static Mock<ImageHandler> mockSut;

    private static BaseHttpHandler sut;

    private Establish context = () =>
    {
        httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        httpRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        mockSut = new Mock<ImageHandler>();

        httpContext.SetupGet(context => context.Response).Returns(httpResponse.Object);
        httpContext.SetupGet(context => context.Request).Returns(httpRequest.Object);

        httpRequest.SetupGet(r => r.RawUrl).Returns("http://logicsoftware/unkown.jpg");

        sut = mockSut.Object;
    };

    private Because of = () => sut.ProcessRequest(httpContext.Object);

    private It should_call_person_with_expected_age = () =>
        {
            mockSut.Verify(s => s.DoPerson(Moq.It.IsAny<Person>()),Times.AtLeastOnce());
        };
}
```

This is really basic stuff, nothing too fancy. Now, when I run the test I get:

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never
>   performed: s => s.DoPerson(It.IsAny()) No setups configured.

I believe this is due to the fact that `sut.ProcessRequest()` is not actually called - I have a breakpoint at the start of ProcessRequest(), but it's never hit. Can someone show me how to setup my mockSut so that `ProcessRequest()` is called.

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a `Mock` of an object with Moq, it will mock the whole object and set it up to return defaults or do nothing on every method and property. So `sut.ProcessRequest`, won't actually do anything: `DoPerson` will never be called.

You'll only want to mock out dependencies to the classes you want to test, never the class itself.

Comment: I tried this same scenario with RhinoMocks and got it working fairly quickly. Not saying Moq is crap, but I just found it a bit fiddly to setup and get running. I normally use TypeMock, but due to changes in work, I will need to start using an open source mocking framework.